# Using cursors to get the query result

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

When performing two different queries, a cursor is used to get the result. However, `row_2` does not get the value that I expected. It seems that it is still using the result in `row`.

```
con = psycopg2.connect(database='db', user='userx')
cur = con.cursor()

res = cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(addr) FROM list_table WHERE addr = '192.168.1.1'")
row = cur.fetchone()

res_2 = cur.execute("SELECT value FROM list_table WHERE addr = '192.168.1.1'")
row_2 = cur.fetchone()

con.commit()
con.close()
```

How can I associate the result of the second query (only) to `row_2` ?

Comment: The same JustWorks(tm) as it should for me (using different database, tables etc of course since I don't have your db), so either there's something else in your code or your expectations about what the second query should return are wrong.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I made some minor modifications and it worked.

Comment: then please close the question.